# If banned from asking questions, can I still answer questions?

Tags: support, post-ban

I have asked poorly worded questions, and read a few meta-questions about being banned from asking questions (i.e. if you are banned from asking, undelete your questions and edit to get upvotes for the automatic reinstatement of question privileges).

If I am banned from asking questions, can I still answer questions?

Comment: FYI, currently you're neither blocked from asking nor from answering.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, yes. Question-bans and answer-bans are almost independent (good answers can help to some extent to lift or avoid a question-ban and vice versa, but the greatest role is played by the posts of the affected type). But if your answers are also poorly received, you can also be answer-banned.

However, question-bans and answer-bans are nowadays not permanent<sup>1</sup> - unless you try really hard - they age away, and mostly are but a rate-limiting. If your questions/answers are poorly received, you will be blocked from asking or answering for a while or limited to ask at most one question per week. If future questions/answers are well-received, that was that. If future questions/answers are also poorly received, you will encounter a new ban, which lasts longer than the previous. But except in extreme cases, that will also expire in a bearable time.

Unlike earlier, undeleting questions to improve them is usually no longer important, the visible content on the site has much greater impact.

<sup>1</sup> The old ban was permanent in the sense that it did not expire after a fixed time. However, it was lifted when certain thresholds of the score/total votes on the content were crossed, so it was not absolutely permanent. The new bans expire automatically after some time (at least the first few iterations).

Comment: How did you guess?

Comment: I believe it is still possible to trigger the "perma-bans", but you essentially have to try. In the [words of Tim Post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243460), "Yes, it _is_ still possible to encounter a much longer-term block on some larger sites, but you'd need to ignore a _lot_ of help before hitting it."